# Is the Zend Framework really a framework or a library?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, terminology

A library can be described as a collections of functionality that *you can call*.

A framework can be described as a pre-made program where in various places you can insert your own code.  The framework then *calls the code for you* at the correct points.

In my many PHP applications, i've been using Zend more as a library, I am creating the "framework" and using what Zend has to offer as a library.

Is the Zend framework really a library?

Comment: In theory, the purpose of the framework "is to write less and do more" in many activities, a library covers only activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be either or both.  Zend is an MVC framework, however many of the components can be called independently of the framework itself.

For instance, I just read [Agile Web Application Development with Yii1.1 and PHP5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199585) and there is a chapter showing how to create an XML feed using the Zend Framework/Library.  So my Yii framework was referencing Zend as a library.  It has great objects and functions, so why not take advantage of them as a library when you can.

Answer (score 2):

Zend is a framework, but it is modular so it can be used as a library.

If you create a full fledged MVC app using the recommended Zend structure, you will be using as a framework.

If you stick a call to Zend::dosomting() in you single page web script, you aren't using the framework.

I appreciate the flexibility Zend gives you.  so called rapid application frameworks like cakephp break down quickly on larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use it it looks to be a library, but that doesn't mean it's not a framework. It can handle pretty much everything for you, but if you just use bits and pieces of its functionality it'd be more like a library.

A pretty big one too. You might wanna partialise it if you only use portions of it.